# X11/XQuartz 'Couldn't find per display information' on Mac Book Pro 2019, OS Monterey

Tags: terminal, display, x11, xquartz, environment-variables

I am trying to run mbsystem (a command-line tool for geodata processing) that for some commands uses a GUI based interface (e.g. if i type 'mbedit' in the command line, a window should open where i can manually edit geodata). For this, i needed to install XQUartz but whenever i try the GUI, the error message 'Couldn't find per display information' occurs.

Xclock, xeyes, xterm all work fine, it's just in combination with mbsystem. I spend ages googling and trying a lot of things, Logging in and out, reinstalling, changing installation order etc. didn't work.

`DISPLAY` is set to `/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Ws5cVK5Ody/org.xquartz:0`, setting it to localhost:0 or just :0 still throws that error.

I'm helpless - can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Do you try to run `mbedit` from Terminal, or do you run it from xterm?

Comment: Also, where did you install mbsystem from, can you link to a page where others could download it from to try themselves?

Comment: And: Has your Mac one monitor or several?

Comment: Hej, htanks for the quick answers!
mbsystem ist from here: https://www.mbari.org/products/research-software/mb-system/
I tried rnning mbedit from both xterm and terminal, zsh and bash, always the same error. 
I just use the laptop without a (second) monitor!